# gdal_retile.py - Set Resolution of finest pyramid

Tags: gdal, geoserver

I have a raster that i want to publish using geoserver. The rasters resolution is 10x10m. However even the smallest tiles in the targetDir have 20x20m resolution and thus my wms has a resolution fo 20x20m as well.

I am using this tutorial:
https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html

Is there a way to do this using gdal_retile? I tried to play with the -ps and the -levels-Setting when running gdal_retile.py

Comment: don't you just need to make one more layer?

Comment: failing that we'll need to see the actual command line you use and an example of your data

Comment: No matter how many levels I use, I did not get a 10x10 pixel layer. I can add some data tomorrow, the data is a Germany-wide 10x10m Raster with integers from 0 to 8 for classes.

Comment: @IanTurton I did a mistake, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I did a mistake in my initial data and the retiling. I used the  -pyramidOnly parameter which is why my 10x10 built the first pyrams at 20x20m resolution.